# Django how to get name of Foreign Key in serializer?

Tags: django, django-serializer

Author is a Foreign Key relation in the model Book

I currently get the output of GET request

```
{
  book:"book1"
  author: 1
}
```

But I want to get the name of the author in JSON

```
{
  book:"book1"
  author: "author"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your current serializer and model?

Answer (score 0):

you can use relationship manager.

```py
b1 = Book.objects.filter(id=1).get()
b1.author.name # if relation is one to one
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I needed from the django-rest-framework official documentation. I needed to use Serializer Relations. In my case the SlugRelatedField works

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/